# How to specify the VS Build Tools 2019 environment from VS 2017's CMakeSettings.json?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I want to specify that CMake should use the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools to build our C++ project (with Ninja) when invoked from Visual Studio 2017.

I am guessing that this can be accomplished by specifying an 'environment' in CMakeSettings.json, tailored for the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools, instead of using one of the predefined environments such as "msvc_x64_x64".

Is there an easy way to do this or would I have to reverse engineer all the environment variables set by a VS 2019 Developer Command Prompt and specify those settings in the 'environment' section of CMakeSettings.json?